# Does data lake analytics has a support to create relational databases

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

It seems data lake analytics has a support to create databases but can we create relational databases too?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "create relational databases"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Azure Data Lake Analytics account can create databases that can contain relational data that you can create, manage and query with U-SQL.

That data is stored in a scaled out fashion inside the Azure Data Lake Storage. So in a sense it is creating relational databases.

However it does not give you the ability to create a SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL database.